# wifi specific data usage on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I want to know is it possible in iOS to get the data usage by specific WIFI even when app is not running. Is there any API which can be used for this to get result?

To know the total WIFI I used following code:

```
- (NSArray *)getDataCounters
{
    BOOL success;
    struct ifaddrs *addrs;
    const struct ifaddrs *cursor;
    const struct if_data *networkStatisc;

    int WiFiSent = 0;
    int WiFiReceived = 0;
    int WWANSent = 0;
    int WWANReceived = 0;

    NSString *name=[[NSString alloc]init];

    success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
    if (success)
    {
        cursor = addrs;
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",cursor->ifa_name];
            //NSLog(@"ifa_name %s == %@\n", cursor->ifa_name,name);
            // names of interfaces: en0 is WiFi ,pdp_ip0 is WWAN

            if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
            {
                if ([name hasPrefix:@"en"])
                {
                    networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                    WiFiSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                    WiFiReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                    //                    NSLog(@"WiFiSent %d ==%d",WiFiSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                    //                    NSLog(@"WiFiReceived %d ==%d",WiFiReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
                }

                if ([name hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip"])
                {
                    networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                    WWANSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                    WWANReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                    //                    NSLog(@"WWANSent %d ==%d",WWANSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                    //                    NSLog(@"WWANReceived %d ==%d",WWANReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
                }
            }

            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }

        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(WiFiSent)/1000000], [NSNumber numberWithInt:(WiFiReceived)/1000000],[NSNumber numberWithInt:(WWANSent)/1000000],[NSNumber numberWithInt:(WWANReceived)/1000000], nil]);

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(WiFiSent)/1000000], [NSNumber numberWithInt:(WiFiReceived)/1000000],[NSNumber numberWithInt:(WWANSent)/1000000],[NSNumber numberWithInt:(WWANReceived)/1000000], nil];
}
```

Please help me with this.